# Google Calendar API - no longer authorized for reads?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

So, using the Calendar API to pull all events from a publicly available Google Calendar.

This were working fine until this morning.

As I'm not updating or doing any data alteration, we've implemented an API key to access read only data as follows:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[calendar ID]/events?timeZone=EDT&timeMin=2020-06-30T04:00:00.000Z&maxResults=6&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&key=[API key]
```

Yesterday, pulled fine, today returns:

> code: 401
> message: invalid credentials

Any thoughts on this? It's affecting several implementations of this calendar code (different keys, domains, etc) but with the same basic methodology.

I have not implemented the gapi client javascript library, may begin looking into that now.

Comment: @DalmTo The issue that he's having, as well as myself, is that the URL formatted as such witth the calendarID and API key no longer work. It's not an issue with his code whatsoever but on Google's end. Interestingly enough on the Google Calendar "Try this API" only OAUTH requests work...

Comment: Related to [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/149772956)

Comment: Above bug has been marked as Invalid. Created new bug in Google Issue Tracker here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160190541

Comment: Looks like Google is working on the issue. I found this in the G Suite Support Assistant, in the Admin Panel of my teams G Suite account.
[Calendar API Service Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLaTQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed by Google. All API key usage should be working as normal.

Looks like they had some issues on their end:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't like adding +1 type responses, but I also suddenly got errors using API keys for the Google Calendar API.

Looking in the Google Console you can see that "API keys" is no longer an enabled credential for the Google Calendar API.

I'm pretty sure it's a mistake as Google should notify everyone before such a huge change. I'm hopeful they find reports of this and it's a mistake that will correct itself soon.

Btw, for anyone else, this is the error returned by Googles API:

```
{
    "error": {
    "errors": [
    {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
    }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials"
    }
    }
```

Comment: I've also had this issue today, From the Google "Try this API" in the documentation only the OAUTH2 authentication options are working for things. Hopefully this is a bug and not a new policy change....

Comment: As a workaround while this issue appears to be continuing, I'm trying to implement the "gapi" client from google. Will share any progress as I move ahead. https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client