# Google Calendar APIKey not working anymore

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I have been retrieving Danish holidays using the Google Calendar Api but suddenly it stopped working.

I would normally just call the URL below using an apikey in the key-parameter for authentication:
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/da.danish%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyAi3_vE6AC1E--9sX3LGjk6lOXh0sSNkr8&timeMin=2020-06-29T00:00:00Z&timeMax=2020-07-06T00:00:00Z&singleEvents=true&maxResults=9999

But now I am getting the follow error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

I tried generating another APIKey but with the same result.

Any ideas why?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, I can retrieve the events successfully with the URL you provided. Can you check if you still can't access it?

Comment: Please be mindful that the answer you received was not correct. Public Calendars can be accessed via API key, and what you were experiencing was caused by a bug.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears that [Google now requires OAuth2 clients to be set up even for public calendars](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth?hl=es_419) like the holidays calendar:

> Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses Google Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.

I used [Google's OAuth2 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to set up access and refresh tokens while in development.

The scope is:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly
```

After that, it would be necessary to set up an OAuth client when a project goes to production.

**UPDATE**

It was Google's issue. [API Keys are working again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659190/google-calendar-api-no-longer-authorized-for-reads).

Answer (score 2):

#### You don't need OAuth in order to access public Calendars, the behaviour you were experiencing was caused by a bug.

You don't need to authorize your request in order to access a public Calendar (anyone can access it, after all), so an API key can be used for that.

While this might change in the future, and while OAuth is the recommended way to access the API, this is the current product behaviour.

The reason you were getting a 401 was because of this bug, which got fixed a few hours later:

- [#160190541. Google Calendar API Key returning 401](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160190541)

Comment: According to the documentation, "Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported."  Where are you seeing documentation indicating OAuth is not necessary for public calendars?
https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth

Comment: @TylerJohnson Since it's a public resource, the request doesn't need to be authorized. There is no explicit documentation on this for Calendar AFAIK, but it's the same behaviour you can see in other APIs where the resource is public (try, for example, retrieving a public Drive file via [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) without OAuth, just with API key). Authorization protocols are required when the resource to access is private.

Comment: @TylerJohnson I see Sheets API has some more explicit statement: `When your application requests public data, the request doesn't need to be authorized, but does need to be accompanied by an identifier, such as an API key.` [Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing). Looks like most API docs don't make this explicit, but the behaviour is the same.

Comment: From Damien at Google Cloud Support: 
"
While the issue was specific to API key access, this is not a documented method for the Calendar API so while this may work at the moment, we do have to recommend that you use the documented methods for this via OAuth.  I can't emphasize the importance of using OAuth with the Calendar API to avoid any issues with this.

As I had mentioned previously there was documentation on using API Key access with the Calendar API previously but this was removed over a year ago and with this, the only supported method we could recommend at this time is OAuth.
"

Comment: @TylerJohnson Do you have a link for that?

Comment: It's from a support ticket. Unfortunately I don't have a public link to provide.

Comment: @TylerJohnson From the [API page](https://developers.google.com/calendar): `You can use the Google Calendar API to find and view public calendar events. If you're authorized, you can also access and modify private calendars and events on those calendars.`. This quote apparently states that you should be able to make requests to the API without being authorized (that is, without OAuth) in order to access public resources (and that's the current behaviour, after all).

Comment: That isn't developer documentation and doesn't say anything about API keys. And it is in conflict with https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth which states:

"Every request your application sends to the Google Calendar API must include an authorization token"..."Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests".

It would be really nice if we could get *public* confirmation from Google whether the existing API key functionality is supported and will be supported in the forseeable future.