# FullCalendar - Google Calendar - Invalid Credentials (401)

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, fullcalendar-5

I am having trouble with an integration with FullCalendar on our websites.  I am currently using version 2.4 (I know it's old, but it was new when I integrated it).  All of our requests (all to public calendars) are being blocked with a 401 (Authorization, Invalid Credentials) error.

So, I downloaded the latest package from the website and loaded the "google-calendar.html" from the examples folder (which appears to use the public "Holidays" calendar), and it is having the same problem.

In addition, the demo on the website appears to suffer from the same error.  You can see it here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar-demo

It appears that maybe something about the Goolge Calendar API changed, and has broken the functionality, but I wanted to see if it might be something I am doing wrong.

Thank you for the help,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

After much research, this appears to be an error with Google Calendar API, and public calendars being able to be accessed by API key's.

Here is the main thread on it: [Google Calendar API - no longer authorized for reads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659190/google-calendar-api-no-longer-authorized-for-reads)

Here is the main bug report at Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160190541

It seems like it is a true bug, and is being fixed by Google.