# Google Calendar API- API key is no longer valid without reason (400)

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I have an application (php) that handles the API for years.
However a few weeks ago it started giving the error sporadically:

(400) API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.

In the end the error was continuous and stopped responding.

I related it to [Google Calendar API - no longer authorized for reads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659190/google-calendar-api-no-longer-authorized-for-reads)

After several days of inactivity, the application worked again for a few days, but the pattern has been repeated again:

It has been giving the error more and more frequently until it has stopped working.

Edited:

The application can be viewed at:

http://intraneteina.unizar.es/intraneteina/index.php?r=calendarioGoo/index

When selecting any option from the dropdown, the application reads information from a google calendar and displays it in html.

It has been working for years, and without touching the code, now it gives the described API error key not valid.

Comment: You might need to contact the developers of the API to find out why it's failing on their end.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code.

Comment: The post you linked references a bug fixed a few days ago, so it could be you still experience it. What are you doing with the API? Do you have the steps to reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

I had been experiencing a similar issue. I found some documentation, eventually, that said there was a limit of 50 (or possibly 100) "active" authorisation tokens allowed for an app unless you are running it via a service account. Typically once the limit is reached Google just drops authorisations off the end of the "active list" it maintains and you are unaware of this happening. This is a problem if you are relying on the expiry of your access token and don't generate a refresh token until you think you need to - i.e. When you generate/refresh your access token you record the expiry date and only refresh it when you system tells you that your token has expired.

Because Google may have disabled that token (dropped it off the active list) in the background and you are unaware of this you try to use that token which hasn't expired - the result is a typically uninformative error message with no indication of what has happened. In our case in the short term setting up a service account was too difficult (implementing RSA256 for the authorisation process) so we got around this by just ignoring the recorded expiry timestamp and requesting a refresh token every time we made a call to the API. I'm sorry I can't link you to the documentation, but I believe I found it via an answer in another S.O. post.

Comment: I found this link very informative .... https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35

Comment: Also this gives some info about the limit... https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration